# Reading form field data in Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms

I just can't get this to work.

HTML:

```
<form action="index.php?page=n0402" method="post" Name="AddPolish" >
    <div id="frmBrandInput">
        <label for="frmBrand">Brand name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="frmBrand" size="50" onkeypress="BrandCheck();" maxlength="100" id="frmBrand" value="Enter existing or new brand"  />
        <span id="frmBrand_Status"></span>
    </div>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
function BrandCheck()
{
    var jsBrandName = document.forms["AddPolish"]["frmBrand"].value;
    alert(jsBrandName);
}
```

Why can't I get the value of frmBrand into jsBrandName? If I use Firebug to debug, I get the following in my Watch list:
Watch Expression:

```
document.forms["AddPolish"]["frmBrand"];
```

Result:

```
NodeList[input#frmBrand property value = "G" attribute value = "Enter existing or new brand", input#frmBrand attribute value = ""]
```

I can see the value "G" which is what I entered in the input field. What am I doing wrong in passing it into the jsBrandName?

Comment: Is that really the *actual* HTML?  Are there more than one "frmBrand" `<input>` elements? That's why the value is a NodeList and not a simple single input element.

Comment: does it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/uFp3V/ ? It works for me.

Comment: I don't think `action='index.php?page=n0402'` will work, with a $_GET URL like `?page=n402`. Use `<input type='hidden' name='page' value='n0404' />` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output you got implies that there are two inputs with `name="frmBrand"` in the form. You need to index them, e.g.

```
var jsBrandName = document.forms["AddPolish"]["frmBrand"][0].value;
```

to get the value of the first one.

Comment: <insert lots of swearing> You were right. Somewhere way down in the html page, I had forgotten to change a frmBrand ID after copy/pasting. Thank you, it works now!